# jQuery. Getting a value span element on the same row with clicked element

Tags: jquery, html, gridview

I'm looking for the way to get a value of one element when clicking the button on the same row.

Here is am html for one of rows:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_0" style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center">222222222 </span>
 </td>
 <td>
    <span id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_0" style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center">Gruzin, Eugene Test      </span>
 </td>
  <td>
    <span id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_0" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center">99</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_0" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center">11111</span>
  </td>
   <td>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$txtgvEmailAddress" type="text" value="test@test.com" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_0" onclick="ResetMessage();" style="width:200px;" />
      <input type="button" value="Update" id="btnEmailUpdate" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get an `id` of my `span` first:

```
var isoNumId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').attr('id');
```

then I want to get a text based on id: `var IsoNumVal = $('#isoNumId').text()`

when checking: `alert(isoNumId)` I get nothing.

What is the best approach?

Thank you

Comment: which value yoyu want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the value of span, try:

```
var isoNumId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) span').attr('id');
```

in your code, you got the id of the first `td`

Comment: Here you go...! Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#btnEmailUpdate").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents("tr").find("span:first").html());
});
```

Comment: That also works. Thx. Good to know more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

http://jsfiddle.net/32yHt/1/

```
$(this).parent().find("span:first").text();
```

This should work as well.